# How to use firestore persistence on React Native Expo app?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access fetched data from firestore offline but persistence its not working, I guess it has to be a problem with JS SDK compatibility.

This is my component:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { getCollection } from './scripts/firebase';

export default function App() 
{
  const getData = async () =>
  {
    const collection = await getCollection("problems");

    console.log(collection);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={getData}>
        <Text>
          Get data
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is my firebase script:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { collection, 
        getDocs, 
        initializeFirestore, 
        persistentLocalCache, 
        persistentSingleTabManager, 
        CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //My firebase config
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = initializeFirestore(app, 
    {
        localCache: persistentLocalCache(
            {
                cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, 
                tabManager: persistentSingleTabManager()
            })
    }
);

export async function getCollection(collectionName)
{  
    const collectionRef = await getDocs(collection(db, collectionName))
    const data = collectionRef.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    return data;
}
```

When I hit the button `Get data`, i get this warning telling me persistence is diasabled:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.1.0): Error using user provided cache. Falling back to memory cache: FirebaseError: [code=unimplemented]: This platform is either missing IndexedDB or is known to have an incomplete implementation. Offline persistence has been disabled.

So, anyone who has worked with persistence in with firestore on react native can tell me how can I achieve using it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using "expo-firestore-offline-persistence". It polyfills indexedDB using "expo-sqlite" and "indexeddbshim". This still works with the FireStore Web modular API (v9). For reference, this is my setup (includes persistence for auth).

```
import "expo-firestore-offline-persistence"; // Make sure this is imported first
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore, persistentLocalCache } from 
"@firebase/firestore";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {
    getReactNativePersistence,
    initializeAuth,
} from "firebase/auth/react-native";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projected: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "",
};

let app;
if (!app) {
    app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

// Fix storing auth session locally by reintroducing Async Storage
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});

// persistentLocalCache is required to enable offline querying
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
    experimentalForceLongPolling: !isProduction,
    localCache: persistentLocalCache(/*settings*/ {}),
});

export { db, auth };
```

Since I use "eas-build" to build my apps, I had to make sure NOT to the latest version of "indexeddbshim" (using 10.1.0 instead) since it depends on "canvas", which does not have a direct build option for arm64 chips (needed for mobile devices), causing the build process on the eas servers to fail.